# Can i pass N count of params to .bind()

Tags: javascript

So here's the thing, lets say I have a function packed into a variable:

```
var myFunction = function(param1, param2) {
    // do stuff
}
```

and I'm doing this:

```
var functionParameters = { data1: 1, data2: 2};
myFunction.bind(null, functionParameters.data1, functionParameters.data2);
```

How can I make this more generic, in case the function will require more parameters?

Because I don't have control over an executable function and parameters.

The function and parameters can be set by the user and I'm just executing them.

Comment: You could create an array from your `functionParameters`                  object and consider [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Comment: Why are you using `myFunction.bind()`? why `bind`?

Answer (score 0):

You may like to try spread operation

```
function fn(a,b,c){
    console.log(a,b,c)
}
```

and you could do

```
const paras = [1,2,3];
const myFun = fn.bind(null, ...paras)
```

It will prints `1,2,3` when you call `myFun()`

However, it only works for array.

If you are looking for a solution for key-value mapping type, you may need to write a glue function that transform the value into array.

For example you have a object type

```
const paras = {b:1, a:2, c:3};
```

you could transform it into array by

```
const arrayParas = ['a','b','c'].map(field => paras[field])
```

And then you can bind your function

```
const myFun = fn.bind(null, ...arrayParas)
```

---

Edit: if you don't know the filed/ how to get parameter name from a function

Js has its toString which will convert a function to string who contains the input parameter of that function.

**But you need to make sure that the name of the input parameters in the function are exactly the same to the field names in the object.**

```js
// get function parameter name
function getParameterNames(func) {
  const STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
  const ARGUMENT_NAMES = /([^\s,]+)/g;
  const fnStr = func.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
  const result = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(') + 1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(ARGUMENT_NAMES);
  if (result === null)
    result = [];
  return result;
}
//
function fn(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c)
}

const paraObjs = {
  c: 3,
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
const fields = getParameterNames(fn);
const paraArray = fields.map(field => paraObjs[field]);
const myFun = fn.bind(null, ...paraArray)

myFun();
```

Comment: this sound as a solution

Comment: any ideas if i don't know the field names and their count?

Comment: @Cheese yes, you can try toString() and parsing the text content to get the parameter (see update). BUT it assume the name of the parameters of the function MUST BE EXACTLY THE SAME as that of the paramObject

Answer (score 0):

If I'm now understanding correctly, you can make use of [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to accomplish this:

```js
var myFunction = function(param1, param2) {
  console.log(param1);
  console.log(param2);
}

var functionParameters = {
  data1: "test",
  data2: "another test"
};

var run = myFunction.bind(null, ...Object.values(functionParameters))
run();
```

---

### Old Answer

I'd imagine the easiest solution would be simply passing an array...

```js
var myFunction = function(args) {
  args.forEach((i) => console.log(i));
}

var functionParameters = {
  1: "test",
  2: "another test",
  3: "another one"
};

var run = myFunction.bind(null, Object.values(functionParameters)) //Get array of values from the object
run();
```

---

If you plan on sending only specific values of the object as you have in your example, you could make use of [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```js
var myFunction = function(...args) {
  args.forEach((i) => console.log(i));
}

var functionParameters = {
  data1: "test",
  data2: "another test",
  data3: "another one"
};

var run = myFunction.bind(null, functionParameters.data1, functionParameters.data2, functionParameters.data3) //Get array of values from the object
run();

//myFunction("This", "function", "will", "now", "take", "unlimited", "parameters");
```

Comment: the object.value would be really great solution if it was supported well

Comment: To add compatible `Object.values` support in older environments that do not natively support it, you can find a **Polyfill** in the [tc39/proposal-object-values-entries](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries) or in the [es-shims/Object.values](https://github.com/es-shims/Object.values) repositories.

Comment: Although, if you're not comfortable using `Object.values`, you definitely should not be using spread syntax either, which both current answers make use of.

Comment: I like more the spread syntax, as if the function will be call with out any params the spread syntax will set a empty array [ ] and he can work with that more easy at the function part. Also not mention but you can try the arguments Object of the function

Comment: In regards to spread syntax, I'm simply saying that if OP is worried about lack of support for `Object.values` (all browsers except IE), then he should not consider using spread syntax either, as it's much newer and less supported.

Comment: i don't get it. why in your answer it eats the array as many parameters, but in my case it thinks i'm passing an array as a first parameter

Comment: It sounds like you didn't include the `...` before `Object.values()`. That's the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) I mentioned - it's converting the array into separate arguments. However, as I added, both answers you've received make use of it, and it's less supported than `Object.values`.

Comment: I don't think it is a perfect solution. The order of the object is quite random and it may not be a valid assumption that Object.values will always yield the correct order of the values.

Comment: @user3003238 That's a fair point, however, ES2015 (which includes Spread Syntax) now guarantees that any non-integer object properties will be returned in the same order in which they were inserted.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but are you sure the order of insertion and the order of the input parameters are the same?

Comment: That's a question for OP, but given the code sample he provided, I'm lead to assume that's the case.